# How I can write the value of mongo objectid in json string in golang

Tags: json, mongodb, go

The objectid is always unique and unpredictable. I want that, this var should take value of primitive.NewObjectID.Hex()

```
var mockData = `{"status":201,"message":"User Created Successfully!","data":{"data":"{"InsertedID":primitive.NewObjectID().Hex()}"}}`
```

But writing it like this gives me a straight string in output.

Comment: In this case you should probably use some BSON package rather than the regular json/encoding. Your mongo library should have docs on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "break" the string literal and concatenate the parts using `+`:

```
var mockData = `{"status":201,"message":"User Created Successfully!","data":{"data":{"InsertedID":"` + primitive.NewObjectID().Hex() + `"}}}`
```

This will work because the hex object ID does not need any special escaping in JSON, but in general you should use the [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) package to generate valid JSON (which knows about proper escaping).

Using the `encoding/json` package this is how it could look like:

```
var s struct {
    Status  int    `json:"status"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Data    struct {
        Data struct {
            InsertedID string
        } `json:"data"`
    } `json:"data"`
}
s.Status = 201
s.Message = "User Created Successfully!"
s.Data.Data.InsertedID = primitive.NewObjectID().Hex()

out, err := json.Marshal(s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-Ax4qAXm2i8).